# Please help me in adding a printer in windows xp mode on windows 7 professional

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp, printers, network-printers

I have an HP Laserjet 2420 PCL6 printer on my network for which drivers are not available for windows 7. I have installed windows xp mode on my windows 7 system, but I am unable to add that printer in Windows XP mode.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the printer to run in WinXP mode? My first inclination would be to run the Windows Vista SP2 drivers in Win 7.

Comment: I am unable to get windows vista sp2 driver either for this printer.

Comment: Pruneet, Are you having an issue finding the driver to download, or getting it to install?   http://bit.ly/fzxM8d is a link to the driver page. But it won't help if you have an install issue. The driver appears to be the same for Win Xp and Win Vista. Do you use teamviewer? I can take a look at your setup if you'd like.

Comment: I have been able to find the driver for windows vista sp2 just a moment back and the printer has been installed on my PC. Thanks, I couldn't guess that vista driver will work on windows 7. But still I am getting "printer is offline" although printer is ON. But thats another issue I think.

Comment: Yeah. HP printers often have that issue. Restart the printer after the driver install. May also require an OS reboot.

Comment: Restarting the print spooler service worked.